# Form Assembly :: Concatenate fields in a Repeatable section

Tags: forms, salesforce

I have a Type and Phone number field in FormAssembly which is repeatable. When users add 2 entries like the one below,

## User Entries:

Type: "Mobile"          Number:6787867890
Type: "Landline"        Number:7898878987

I need to concatenate the above entries to a single field like the one below using Calculation Fields

## Expected Result:

Mobile:6787867890|Landline:7898878987

Any idea on how this can be achieved using Calculation fields in FormAssembly?

Answer (score 0):

Just got this working by using 2 Calculation Fields. In the Repeatable section, I added a Calculation field(vEntries) which is hidden. vEntries will concatenate Type: "Mobile" Number:6787867890 to "Mobile:6787867890".

I declare another Calculation field(vFinalEntry) outside the repeatable section, this field is responsible for concatenating all the vEntries.

So when the user enters the second entry Type: "Landline" Number:7898878987, the  vFinalEntry variable will have the value "Mobile:6787867890|Landline:7898878987".